# IAP and third party purchasing

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have a question about in app purchases. My company charges customers for access to our software system. They are charged to use the system (subscription fee) and then can opt to use higher quality data (satellite imagery). We have multiple imagery sources but one that provides better imagery (5 meter resolution vs 30 meter resolution) charges for it (the lesser quality imagery is government provided and free) and we pass that cost to the user in the form of credits. We require the user to per-purchase credits to "activate" a boundary (provided imagery is available at that location).

Apple allows us to "activate" and charge against a customer's credits (at least hasn't rejected the app based on this yet).

My question is if we can use our own purchasing system to add credits in the app? It does not unlock features in the app. Anything you can do with the higher quality data, you can do with the other free data.

> In the App Store Review Guidelines (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies), section 11.3 states:
>
> Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected

Does this mean we are allowed to use our own purchasing system to process payments for goods and services used outside the app? These same credits can be spent through other software we provide as well as third part software (we offer third party support through our APIs).

Answer (score 0):

I need to preface this with several caveats

- Carefully read all of your Apple contracts
- Nothing is guaranteed - Apple's reviewers can be touchy in this area and Apple has been known to change the rules in this area
- Until you build and submit it, I doubt anyone can give an authoritative answer - all of this is opinion.

I believe Apple will allow this but will not allow you to, in any way, encourage users to use (including links or text references to) the alternative method of payment from within the App. The rule is they want a 30% cut of any revenue the application generates.  Only if the revenue is generated elsewhere can they be cut out.  Amazon Kindle app has fought this battle.  Also note that once they get the idea that this revenue is somehow "theirs" then it will be difficult to convince them otherwise.  Be very careful on that first submission.